# Use result from TIMEDIFF in same query

Tags: php, mysql

I am tryin to substract 10 hours from the difference between starttime and endtime in the same query

```
SELECT id, 
user_id,
starttid,
sluttid,
dato,
TIMEDIFF(sluttid, starttid) as hourDiff,
SUBBTIME(hourDiff, '10:00:00:0000') as overTime
FROM hours
WHERE user_id = :id
ORDER BY dato
```

My problem is that hourDiff does not work, it seems that mysql sees it as a column in this query.. - how can i do, what i am trying?

Comment: You can't refer to a column alias in the same SELECT clause. You will need to use the full expression behind that alias instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you guide me a little more? I have been stuck with this for like 3 hours, trying to research my way out of this - but now i am clueless. Can i do somekind of nested SELECT?

Comment: Can you post a sample row?

Comment: Hey viney - the answer that was given below was what i needed :) But thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant to use `SUBTIME` not `SUBBTIME`.  Repeat the expression that generates `hourDiff` in `SUBTIME`.  Try this:

```
SELECT id, 
user_id,
starttid,
sluttid,
dato,
TIMEDIFF(sluttid, starttid) as hourDiff,
SUBTIME(TIMEDIFF(sluttid, starttid), '10:00:00:0000') as overTime
FROM hours
WHERE user_id = :id
ORDER BY dato
```

Comment: This is exactly what i meant! SUB(B)TIME was a misspell in the paste - but was right in the code. But i get the point now on how to do this. 

And now i understand paul spiegels comment aswell. Thank you for making me understand.